# Firebase storage slow download even with small files

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-storage

Why is it so slow to download an image? I get the same results for 60kb image and 1MB image file
it's always around 0.6 seconds to download it (avg)
is there a minimum processing time no matter how small the file is?

```
    const long maxAllowedSize = (1 * 1024*1024);
    storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://myproject.appspot.com/1mbImage.jpg");
    DateTime before = DateTime.Now;

    var task2 = await storage_ref.GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).ContinueWith(t => t);

    DateTime after = DateTime.Now;
```

I made a button to download the same image, the first click is about 0.9 seconds, the second click is 0.6, 0.4, 0.7 and so on.
I tried to download both from android phone wi-fi, and Unity editor Windows, I have fast internet (227mbps per second)
And I want to download multiple images- the user waits 4 seconds, it's so frustrating, please help

Comment: Try to add some log statements after each step so that we can know where  it's getting slowed. There maybe delay in loading from storage to app.

Comment: I already mentioned in the code Datetime before, and DateTime after... the log gives (the difference) 0.6 seconds on avg... it's not a long code to debug, the only big command in the code is GetBytesAsync and it takes 0.6